# Why I cannot do TIN Interpolation in QGIS?

Tags: python, algorithm, vector, interpolation, qgis

I want to do TIN Interpolation on a layer but when I fill all the fields with the right data (vector layer, interpolation attribute, extent etc) the algorithm does not run and shows me this message:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.14/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\TinInterpolation.py", line 188, in processAlgorithm
writer.writeFile(feedback)
Exception: unknown
Execution failed after 0.08 seconds**

Does anybody have an idea about it?? Thank you

Comment: Your post is a bit vague. What kind of layer (vectorial? Points?). What is your version of QGIS? What kind of tin operations? Also notice there is a stack dedicated to GIS questions. You may ask to migrate if necessary. But first fill in details.

Comment: Ok I will try the stack of GIS questions if I won't manage to find a solution. Otherwise I will be more specific in this platform soon. Thank you for your response and a happy new year!!

Comment: I have the same problem now. Did you find a solution for the problem? Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I converted a dxf file into a shape file and then I tried to use Tin interpolation but it didn't work. Then I realized that, in my dxf file, there were some very very small lines and polyline and, after removing them, the interpolation went just fine. I don't really have an explanation but maybe this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of some small lines that are in your file that cannot be handled by Interpolation. You can use Generalizer3 in QGIS plugins to remove those lines.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by using a point based shape-file as opposed to a polygon based shape-file.

Error was non helpful for me as well.

---

Details

```
OS: Mac Sonoma 14.2
3.34.1-Prizren
```